# DateTime parse bug in WinRT Windows 8 RTM?

Tags: c#, datetime, windows-8, windows-runtime, .net-4.5

Having upgraded to Windows 8 RTM, some date time parsing code that I had has stopped working.  I've replicated this using a standard console app:

```
CultureInfo provider;

provider = new CultureInfo("en-US");

string testDate = "1/1/2012";

DateTime date = DateTime.MinValue;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(testDate, 
      CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern,  // (dd/MM/yyyy)
      provider,
      DateTimeStyles.None,
      out date))
    Console.WriteLine("Date: {0}", date);
else
    Console.WriteLine("Can't parse date: {0} / {1}", testDate, date);

Console.ReadLine();
```

Outputs: `Can't parse date: 1/1/2012 ...`

I've also tried making the culture info "eb-GB" (as it makes no difference for the given format).  **However**, if I change the input date to `01/01/2012`, it works fine.

Has something changed in the .net 4.5 DateTime framework that affects this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `ShortDatePattern` to use the one from the selected provider rather than the one in `CurrentCulture`.

```
DateTime date = DateTime.MinValue;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(testDate, 
      provider.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern, // Change this line
      provider,
      DateTimeStyles.None,
      out date))
    Console.WriteLine("Date: {0}", date);
else
    Console.WriteLine("Can't parse date: {0} / {1}", testDate, date);
```

Comment: Ah - presumably the default short date format change for en-GB in RTM?

Comment: @pm_2 Out of curiosity, what _is_ the `ShortDatePattern` in `en-GB` now?

Comment: dd/MM/yyyy - I must admit, I never actually checked it previously because it was working :-)

Comment: Can it be that you just gut lucky when you ran the code previously and that the selected culture and the CurrentCulture happen to be the same?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the `ShortDatePattern` you use is really `"dd/MM/yyyy"`? Maybe `CurrentCulture` is something you don't expect.

Other than that, there's a difference between `"d/M/yyyy"` and `"dd/MM/yyyy"` if you use them to *format* your `DateTime`. Maybe the *parsing* of `DateTime` has now become more strict and reflects the difference between `"d/M/yyyy"` and `"dd/MM/yyyy"`?